# How do i bind an <img> tag of html with the blob uri to display the image on ui, if i am storing images in my blob?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, razor

I am storing images inside azure blob and I want to display the images back on UI, but I want to bind my img tag with the blob uri. 
How do I bind an <img> tag of html with the blob uri to display the image on UI?

this is my controller...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.path = @"F:\download_button_small2.png";
        return View();
    }

    public FileContentResult myAction(string path)
    {        
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        byte[] imageInBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        //upload image to blob and URL in table
        ImageContainer img = new ImageContainer();
        string imageUri = img.insert(fileName, imageInBytes);
        //returns back the image uri from Blob Storage            
        return new FileContentResult(imageInBytes, "image/png");
    }      
}
```

this is my index:

<img src="@Url.Action("myAction","Home", new { path=ViewBag.path})" />

I am trying the commented part i.e. searching for the way to pass uri to the img tag...but not getting any where... so please help out with , what changes i have to make in my controller as well as in my index to get the desired result.

Comment: Where is this image stored? You mentioned blob storage but your code mentions a local drive path hence the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have saved the image in blobstorage, it can be accessed from

```
http://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>
```

Modify your action method to return a string with that URL as its value.

Also, make sure your storage account is set to public access.

**See the following for more details about working with Azure Blob Storage:**

[Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)

[Azure Bits #2 – Saving The Image To Azure Blob Storage](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/rrobinson/azure-bits-2-saving-the-image-to-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: What if the you don't want to make the blob PUBLIC?

Comment: You need to generate SAS token and add it to query string